# CLT for random variables with heavy tails

Tags: probability-theory

The simplest form of classic CLT can be put in the following form:

If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $1$, then the distribution of the normalized sum $$\frac{X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges to that of the Gaussian.

Is there any result as following?

If $X_i$ are i.i.d. with infinite variance, then $$\frac{X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n}{n^{1/\alpha}}$$ converges in distribution to a Cauchy random variable.

If so, what should be $\alpha$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are results of this form, but the sample mean doesn't necessarily converge to a Cauchy distribution--there's a whole family of distributions called the [stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) which can be limits like this. The Normal and Cauchy distributions are just two of them, and all but the Normal have infinite variance, so just having infinite variance isn't enough to converge to the Cauchy--you need exactly the right tail behavior.

In addition to there being infinitely many possible limiting distributions (including asymmetric ones), there are infinitely many possible values of $\alpha$ in your partial sum. In the case where the $X_i$ are i.i.d. Cauchy, we can take $\alpha = 1$ and the mean we get is also Cauchy. In other cases, though, if the distributions have different tail behavior and converge to a different stable distribution, normalizing factor will be different.

Comment: Christenen: Thanks for the answer. Do you know the correct statement for which Cauchy is the limiting distribution?

Comment: @Kumara $(\sum X_i - a_n)/b_n$ will converge to a Cauchy distribution for some values of $a_n$ and $b_n$ if both tails are asymptotically like $|x|^{-2}$ (like the Cauchy distribution, unsurprisingly). There isn't a set sequence for the $b_n$; it can vary from case to case.

Comment: Christenen: Are saying that there exists $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $(\sum X_i - a_n)/b_n$ converges to Cauchy but the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not explicitly known or they don't have closed form expresion?

Comment: You can probably find the $a_n$ and $b_n$ in any particular case, but they're not always the same, like they are in the finite-variance CLT. The $a_n$ are like subtracting off the mean, but distributions like the Cauchy don't have a mean, so that doesn't make sense; it's still a centering operation of some kind. The $b_n$ are like dividing by $\sigma\sqrt n$, but you can't divide by the standard deviation because it's infinite, so you need some other sort of scaling operation that will vary from case to case. Basically, there's not a general form for the $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Christenen: My question is whether $a_n$ and $b_n$ are known for the Cauchy case.

Comment: $X_n$ and $Y_n$ might both converge to Cauchy, but have different forms for $a_n$ and $b_n$. **There is not a general form!**